# Problema scatterplot - Anotar únicamente markers específicos

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando en un scatterplot simple desarrollado con la librería de matplotlib. El problema es que el scatterplot contiene muchos puntos, y me gustaría anotar únicamente los destacados. La única manera que encuentro de hacerlo es anotando todos, y he probado filtrando pero al introducirlos mediante el bucle se anotan puntos aleatorios del gráfico. ¿Alguien sabe cómo podría arreglarlo?

```html
# Objetos
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Utilizamos la función .scatter()
ax.scatter(df["SCA"]['SCA90'], df["GCA"]['GCA90'], alpha = 0.5)

for i, txt in enumerate(df['info']['Player']):
    ax.annotate(txt, (df["SCA"]['SCA90'][i] + 0.01, df["GCA"]['GCA90'][i] + 0.01))

# Formato figura.
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10)
fig.set_dpi(130)
```

[image: scatterplot. los markers que me gustaría anotar son los del rectángulo]

Comment: Recomendación, la próxima vez agrega tus datos, eso hará que más personas se interesen en ayudarte, sin los datos tenemos que invertir más tiempo para generar un ejemplo funcional que debería haber sido agregado por ti. Agregué una respuesta de como anotar únicamente los puntos de interés, pero para revisar tu problema que genera puntos extras no es posible hacerlo sin el código completo y tus datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días @HeytalePazguato.

Antes de nada agradecerte tu tiempo y para la próxima no me olvidaré de poner los datos, puede que así reciba más ayuda.

De todas formas, logré hacerlo mediante una condición if de manera muy simple. Lo pongo por aquí por si le sirve de ayuda a alguien en un futuro.

```
for num, i in enumerate(df['info']['Player']):
if (df['SCA']['SCA90'][num] > 3) & (df['GCA']['GCA90'][num] > 0.5):
    ax.annotate(i, (df["SCA"]['SCA90'][num] + 0.01, df["GCA"]['GCA90'][num] + 0.01))
```

Quizá de haber tenido más experiencia habría logrado antes la solución, puesto que una vez solucionado parece más simple de cómo lo planteé. Muchas gracias y disculpen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Es posible anotar únicamente los datos de interés (En tu pregunta no especificas cuántos puntos de interes tienes) con el método `annotate()`. Debes utilizar un ciclo tal como ya lo descubriste pero lo que te hace falta es crear listas con tus datos de interés, para así crear las anotaciones solo de esos puntos.

En el ejemplo siguiente cree las listas `xvals` y `yvals` como ejemplo de los valores de interés que quisieras anotar, en este caso son el máximo y el mínimo de los puntos generados.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generando datos para el ejemplo
np.random.seed(19680801)
x = np.arange(0.0, 50.0, 2.0)
y = x ** 1.3 + np.random.rand(*x.shape) * 30.0
s = np.random.rand(*x.shape) * 100 + 100

# Generando los datos de interés
xvals = [x[np.argmax(y)], x[np.argmin(y)]]
yvals = [y.max(), y.min()]

# Marco para las anotaciones
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
# Flechas para las anotaciones
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->")
# kwargs para las anotaciones
kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords="offset points", arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props)


# Creando la gráfica
plt.scatter(x, y, s, c="g", alpha=0.5, label="Suerte")
plt.xlabel("Duende")
plt.ylabel("Oro")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

for i in range(len(xvals)):
    # Texto de las anotaciones
    text = "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xvals[i], yvals[i])
    
    # Crear anotaciones
    plt.annotate(text, xy=(xvals[i], yvals[i]), xytext=(10, 20), **kw)


plt.show()
```

Esto devuelve:

[image: Gráfica con anotaciones en máximo y mínimo]

Lo que haría falta es poner la posición de los marcos donde tú desees, en este ejemplo solo los puse con coordenadas relativas (10,20) de los puntos de interés